# Seeking USB-C Female PCB Connector for Razer Kraken X Headphones Adaptation

Tags: pcb, usb, connector, usb-c

I’ve recently undertaken a project to adapt my Razer Kraken X USB headphones from a USB-A to a USB-C connection. Originally, these headphones featured a male USB-A cable designed for PC connection. I modified them by removing the USB-A cable and soldering a male USB-C terminal from an OTG adapter. The modification works well; however, I’m struggling to find high-quality, soft cables like the USB-C cables used for iPhones. Specifically, I needeed a cable with a female USB-C on one end and a male USB-C on the other (didn't found).

My question is: does anyone know of a PCB or adapter that would allow me to attach a female USB-C connection directly? (I have found only USB-C to USB A unidirectional adapters, and don't known how to recognize USB A male to USB C Female adapter)The goal is to use the headphones and be able to disconnect the cable from the earpiece on the headband.

I’ve tried several PCBs from Amazon, but none have met my requirements:

1. [chenyang/Type-C USB-C to USB 2.0 OTG Adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B077S1G4HX): Seems to be unidirectional. Not working
2. [YoungSelly/Connectors usb C/Tunderbold compatible](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0C6M4797B) : Not even working
3. [ANMBEST/USB 3.1 type C Conector 24 Pin](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09WCSF8FC): USB C To USB A unidirectional
4. [Cermant/USB 3.1 Type C 16pin for data transfer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0CB395L99): USB C To USB A unidirectional
5. [ANMBEST/USB 3.1 type C Conector 24 Pin](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0B55XVMKP): USB C To USB A unidirectional
6. [Henrety/Adapter USB C to USB, OTG converter Thunderbolt 4 typeC, adapter USB C male to USB 3.0 female](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BW8ZDSFV): It worked, but only with USB C Male output
7. [Satechi/OTG type A male to type C female](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07KCL8WZK): It works but not in the direction I want.

Any recommendations or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

Some image here:
[image: project so far]

Comment: `PCB available on Amazon` ... shopping questions are not allowed here

Comment: And please-please use decimal enumeration of your variants instead of marketoidal bullets - it is nearly impossible to address any particular variant of your attempts.

Comment: Based on your comments I updated the question

Comment: Your entire approach is wrong. If you want a Type-C port on your device, you should built-in a USB-C receptacle, not a plug. BTW, USBc male to USBc-female are not defined in USB specifications as valid configuration, and this hack (the cable) should not exist.

Comment: @Ale..chenski Right Now the headphones are working with item 6. They provide a USB C male output. I use the cable (which is female to male) and it works good. The problem with that is the cable. It is not soft. So I want to use an adapter to replace the product 6 for some article that converts USB  A cable (from headphones) to USB C female, so I will be able to use some soft cable like iphone usb C cable.

Comment: You can't get flexible C-C detachable cable because the cables require at least 500 mA current carry capacity, and therefore all cables will be thick. Also, you need only USB2, but the cable is SuperSpeed and has extra 4 wires. If you would limit yourself to captive cable, then no one cares about cable ampacity as long as it meets power requirements of your particular design. Also, do you have 5.1k pull-downs on CC1 and CC2 pins of your connector?

Comment: @Ale..chenski I dont see any 5.1k pull-down on pins of my cable. I have been using the Iphone USB C- USB-C cable which is really soft. This has two male terminals, so this is why I was looking a OTG devide to tear down and connect the USB A cables from headphone to OTG usb A entry and obtain a USB C female out from the headphone, so I will be able to connect the thin usb c- usb c iphone cable. This would work?

Comment: I meant the connector glued to your headphones. As a device, the port must have pulldowns.

Comment: @Ale..chenski oh. It may have it because it works perfectly. I just want modify it to have USB C female port instead male

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usual solution to your problem of adapting a USB-A captive cable (as on many headsets) to a USB-C port is to buy a simple adapter like this one:
[image]

No modification of any sort is needed.

Comment: How do you known this is the right direction? USB A to usb C female? 
The product 7 (Satechi) seemed to be similar but it was in opposite directional. Those devices are not bidirectional

Comment: @LF Your link 7 is the opposite direction, at least judging from the picture (note the female connector).

Comment: Okay. I see. So I should search for USB C to USB A. And what about the “host” mode? It is only on OTG adapters. Should I search that? Because PCB I found didn’t had that “host” mode.

Comment: @LF, your item #6 should be working. If you have USB-A receptacle (female), it always supposed to be a HOST (with rare exception of nonstandard A-A cables). The item shown in my post is designed to go into USB-C port. The USB-C male plug in the dongle has all necessary attributes to turn the C-port into HOST mode, and your headphones should be happy.